# Buying reputation points

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Is it possible to buy reputation on stack overflow? It seems that the people do answer more efficiently if bounty is offered :)

Comment: sure, send me £100/$ and I'll use all my votes on your questions. Refund not avalible when the anti-cheat system detects and deletes the votes.

Comment: Excellent idea. +1

Answer (score 6):

Simply answer is: No, you can only earn reputation points.

A few posts on MSO that are relevant:
[How to Buy Rep Only for Use as a Bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69537/how-to-buy-rep-only-for-use-as-a-bounty)
[Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)
[Pay money to SO for quick support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support)

And note that this is Meta **Super User**, not Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looking at the downvotes for this and related questions I guess it is considered very bad by the community even to think about it. Got the point :)